# Initialize objects of another class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have 4 files `index.php, Database.php, Zoo.php, Animal.php`

`// Zoo.php`

```
class Zoo {
    private $db;
    private $animals = array();

    public function __constructor(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->getAllAnimals();
    }

    private function getAllAnimals() {
        //Database stuff, returns an array with all animals
        $p=0;
        foreach($dbresult as $an){
            $animals[$p++] = new Animal($an['name'], $an['age'], $an['weight']);
        }
    }

    public function listAnimals() {
        foreach ($this->animals as $a){
            echo $a->name;
            //and so on
        }
    }
}
```

`// Animal.php`

```
class Animal {
    // variables for the animals
}
```

`// index.php`

```
<?php
    include 'Database.php';
    include 'Zoo.php';

    $db = new Database();
    $zoo = new Zoo($db);
    $zoo->listAnimals();
?>
```

This is from the top of my head, so if there are some errors, just treat it as pseudocode :)

My problem:
I get a `Fatal Error` `Class Animal not found`.
If I add `include 'Animal.php';` in the first line of `Zoo.php`, right before `class Zoo {` it works.

I'm stil learning about OOP with php, and the include-line strikes me as odd, so I ask for someone to help me out with this.
Is there another way to use "Animal"-objects in the "Zoo"-class, without the include or is it normal to use include, or maybe require/require_once?

Comment: `This is from the top of my head, so if there are some errors, just treat it as pseudocode :)` No. Post the actual testcase you're using for debugging.

Comment: `the include-line strikes me as odd` Why's that, then?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that most OOP developers these days take advantage of [__autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) or (even better) the [SPL autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), even if only in the libraries and frameworks that they use.

Comment: Start by looking at the number of frameworks and libraries that use autoloaders

Comment: That's not necessarily "most OOP developers"

Comment: In that case, I retract my "most", and replace it with "I believe that most"... though there's probably (in my opinion) more than a few people using Drupal or Symfony or Zend or any of a myriad of libraries and frameworks that use autoloaders. I believe that there are PHP developers who do use these

Comment: Better ;) I can probably agree with you now

Answer (score 1):

If you need the "Animal" class inside Zoo.php, `require_once("Animal.php");` at the top of Zoo.php. If you need it in some other file, do the same over there.

Answer (score 0):

> the include-line strikes me as odd

Why's that, then? To use `Animal` you must include its definition. Always seemed pretty rational to me.

There are alternatives such as `require` and `require_once` that do the same thing (but with some added restrictions), and some more exotic alternatives such as autoloading. But for simple tasks, `include` will do just fine.